# Is there a Mac inventory editor for Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've got a minecrack inventory editor for Macs running on local maps but what about for the 'classic' server setup? There are clearly one-per-user inventory files in the server world directory but my InvEdit won't open these files, so I'm looking for a tool (ideally mac-native) that can deal with these files.

Comment: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Programs_and_Editors contains all notable software created by the Minecraft community. You should take a look at it. If it isn't there, no such software exists or it isn't stable enough for its intended purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you trying to do? If you want to cheat items, you can just use the /give command to generate item or block.

Comment: Didn't know I could do that sorry, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the INVedit tool, just search on the Minecraft Forums and download any version, there's plenty of guides on how to make it work on Mac in the thread.

Alternatively (this is much easier) install the TooManyItems mod (also on the Minecraft Forums), which will allow you to get any item imaginable, in-game with a nice UI.